# ngx-chips autocomplete returns value along with display string

Tags: angular, ngx-chips

I am following this very basic example https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-chips-example

**component.ts**

```
export interface AutoCompleteModel {
  value: any;
  display: string;
}

 public items = [
    {display: 'Pizza', value: 1},
    {display: 'Pasta', value: 2},
    {display: 'Parmesan', value: 3},
  ];
```

**component.html**

```
<tag-input [ngModel]="['@items']" >
     <tag-input-dropdown  [autocompleteItems]="items" [showDropdownIfEmpty]="true" [dynamicUpdate]="false"></tag-input-dropdown>
 </tag-input>
```

But, my result comes like this

[image]

Value is displayed along with display. How to remove the value?

Answer (score 1):

as per my understanding, you should use `[(ngModel)]="selectedItem"` for that.

```
<div class="force-to-the-bottom">
  <tag-input [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
    <tag-input-dropdown
      [autocompleteItems]="items"
      [showDropdownIfEmpty]="true"
      [dynamicUpdate]="false"
    >
    </tag-input-dropdown>
  </tag-input>
</div>

<pre>{{selectedItem | json}}</pre>
```

Comment: [(ngModel)]="selectedItem"  does not work. But, if I remove all the divs in my html and place only this piece of code, the original example seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, if you don't want to display the default value you only need to remove `[ngModel]="['@items']"` :

```
<tag-input>
   <tag-input-dropdown
    [autocompleteItems]="items"
    [showDropdownIfEmpty]="true"
    [dynamicUpdate]="false">
   </tag-input-dropdown>
</tag-input>
```

I tried with your stackblitz and it seems to work:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-chips-example-wq27q1

Comment: I tried it without the ngModel. Sadly, It still shows the value.

Comment: Can you update your stackblitz with your example? Maybe there is something else

Comment: One difference is I use Angular 7. Another difference is in the example,    import { TagInputComponent } from './shared/tag-input/tag-input.component'; I am not importing this as I get an error as TagComponent is already part of TagModule.

Comment: you should import your own taginputcomponent(if you have one) rather than explicitly importing TagModules's component. kindly check the import for this. Keeping this aside, as requested , make a stackblitz , that showcases what you have tried, so that we could fix it.

Comment: KiraAG. Understand, I have already imported in my appmodule. By the way, I found that removing <form></form> tag from my component.html fixed the issue. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

When using assigning a reference as the value for a child component input property `[ngModel]="selectedItemsList"`, do not forget to declare that reference `selectedItemsList` in the parent component's  class.

Answer (score 0):

For me I found the problem to be hinted by a console error:

> Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or
>   the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

so just adding a name attribute to the tag-input should solve the problem.. :

```
<tag-input [ngModel]="['@items']" name="SOME_NAME">
  <tag-input-dropdown  [autocompleteItems]="items" [showDropdownIfEmpty]="true" [dynamicUpdate]="false"></tag-input-dropdown>
</tag-input>
```

Hope it helps somebody